# Nginx -- check whether variables are included

Tags: nginx

I have declared a variable like: set $virtual 23833403,250872188;

then I use below to judge whether $virtual contains url's param in location.

```
    location / {            
       if ($virtual ~* $arg_code) { 
            return 301 https://www.aaa.com;
       } 
    }
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: url like: https://www.bbb.com/index.html?code=23833403&language=en

Comment: Nginx does not have the ability to compare a parameter with a comma separated list. If you declare the list of numbers as a [`map` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map), you may have more success.

Comment: You can't use a variable as a regex pattern or its part, all regex patterns are compiled at the startup time. You need to find another way to do whatever you need.

Comment: @RichardSmith The problem was solved as you said. Thank you very much.